# Convert text date/time to as date time format in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Data is extracted from the application. There is a text representation of data/time as

**"Wed Nov 30 2022 09:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"** (in text)

I am required to format this column as MS data/time type, instead of text

#### First:

Tried custom format.. but didn't work.
not able to teach "Wed" and "GMT..." part

#### Second:

Tried to break the words as
`=MID(A1,5,20)`   [it gives  "Nov 30 2022 09:30:00" ]

and then apply.
`=TIMEVALUE(TEXT(RIGHT(B1,8),"HH:MM:SS"))`

It worked and excel was able to understand it in time format as`9:30:00 AM`

But, when I applied similarly the Date format as
`=DATEVALUE(TEXT(LEFT(B1,11),"mmm dd yyyy"))`

It gave a Value error, not sure what to do next

#### Finally:

Is there a way to do it in one go?
the entire column can be formatted as a valid date and time.

I took inspiration from:
[question]: [Convert text date/time to a real date time in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36259951/convert-text-date-time-to-a-real-date-time-in-excel)
[blog]: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-numbers-as-dates-or-times-418bd3fe-0577-47c8-8caa-b4d30c528309

Kindly advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, perhaps for now, I have tried this one,

[image]

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=LET(_string,TEXTSPLIT(MID(A1,5,20),," "),
_date,DATE(INDEX(_string,3),MONTH(INDEX(_string,1)&1),INDEX(_string,2)),
_time,TIMEVALUE(INDEX(_string,4)),
_date+_time)
```

---

Another way,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(MID(A1,5,20),11)," ",", ",2))+RIGHT(MID(A1,5,20),8)+0
```

---

`DATEVALUE()` wrapping not required actually,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(MID(A1,5,20),11)," ",", ",2)+RIGHT(MID(A1,5,20),8)
```

---

Use `LET()` to make it more readable,

[image]

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=LET(_extract,MID(A1,5,20),
_datepart,LEFT(_extract,11),
_timepart,RIGHT(_extract,8),
SUBSTITUTE(_datepart," ",", ",2)+RIGHT(_timepart,8)+0)
```

---

One more sleek way is using `TEXTBEFORE()` & `TEXTAFTER()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1," ")," GMT")," ",", ",2)
```

---

**Note:** Since in Excel Date and Times are stored as number this will return as a number, The integer portion of the date serial number represents the day, and the decimal portion is the time, hence format it accordingly as per your need or regional settings.